# Different behaviour of Numeric columns in postgres and Snowflake

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a tbale both inm snowflake and postgres
in postgres the numeric column is defined as numeric(20,6)
in snowflake also it is defined as numeric(20,6)
but when I am doing the sum of that column I am getting value like :

```
 0.00123 in postgres and
 0.000124 in snowflake
```

Now again I jumped into snowflake and changed the column definition to (20,5)
then, I got the same result as in postgres that is 0.00123

can anyone explain this strange behaviour of snowflake

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `0.00123` and `0.000124` differ by an order of magnitude.  Does your data have some typo in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review, if the below migration guide might be of help:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/PostgreSQL-to-Snowflake-ETL-Steps-to-Migrate-Data

Comment: Thanks alot @FKaynai . I have bookmarked the given link.

Comment: It is making no differnce but @FKayani, still snowflake is rounding off

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was in postgres
It was truncating the decimal digits after 6 places in the query result set, but when I exported the results in excel file, the data was same as it was giving in snowflake